# Paging in MVC with bootstrap

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap, pagination

I have a MVC web application and have list of categories and there are many categories which make a page long. bootstrap css is easy to integrate in MVC application for paging.

Answer (score 4):

MVC 4 Paging with bootstrap or without bootstrap design also has different options like ItemTexts, TooltipTitles, Size, Alignment, IsShowControls, ItemIcon, metro css supported.

Demo [Ajax Paging With Bootstrap In MVC 4](http://mvcpaging.apphb.com/)

Now mvc paging areas supported.
[nuget Package MVC 4 Paging 3.0.0](http://nuget.org/packages/MVC4.Paging/)